# How does WiFiServer.status() work?

Tags: esp8266, wifi

What are the possible outcomes of calling `status()` on a `WiFiServer` from `ESP8266WiFi.h`? The only documentation I could find only says it returns `uint8_t`. Here's the [link](https://links2004.github.io/Arduino/da/de6/class_wi_fi_server.html#ad16f936581fd4d415910a52410291588).

Comment: `wl_status_t` at this page https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/include/wl_definitions.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic set of functions of the esp8266 WiFi object follows the API of the Arduino's first WiFi library for Arduino WiFi Shield. It is [documented here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi).

The esp8266 implementation of status() focuses on state of the STA and maps SDK status to some of Arduino documented codes.

```
wl_status_t ESP8266WiFiSTAClass::status() {
    station_status_t status = wifi_station_get_connect_status();

    switch(status) {
        case STATION_GOT_IP:
            return WL_CONNECTED;
        case STATION_NO_AP_FOUND:
            return WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL;
        case STATION_CONNECT_FAIL:
        case STATION_WRONG_PASSWORD:
            return WL_CONNECT_FAILED;
        case STATION_IDLE:
            return WL_IDLE_STATUS;
        default:
            return WL_DISCONNECTED;
    }
}
```